# ObjectBox dynamic queries

Tags: flutter, objectbox

e.g. the end user makes selections from two of five possible filters, the last three filters being left as ‘all’.

Rather than me creating queries for every possible combination of the 5 filters (25 different queries in total), what is the most efficient syntax for handling this?

Should I use .and to chain the queries together, and then can I specify ‘all’ for any which are not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **query builder** can be used to build the query according to the selected filters. That is adding query criteria only using inside `if` conditions checking for the the filters.

Comment: Hi Vahid, I can't see any way to include an if statement. e.g. if a certain filter is selected then query by this criteria, and if not then skip this part of the query. Could you provide a short example of using if to satisfy this type of filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows. Use a ternary operator ?: and in the second condition query one of the values with .notNull()
This gives the result of 'all', effectively ignoring this part of the query.

This is a hack, but it works. It is obviously an expensive solution, as the ideal would be to skip over unwanted filters completely.

Note to developer: 'if' cannot be used within query structure in dart. Thanks for finding time to respond, hopefully my additional info helps.